# How much faster could I make this script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

I have noticed that the script is significantly faster when I comment out the line that calls `setValues()`. Not that it's a super big issue, but I am interested in the different ways (if any) that I could speed the process up. If anyone has some insight, I would greatly appreciate it! It would also help me see where I could make similar optimizations in other parts of my script.

Here is the code in question:

```
// import new value(s)
  if ((numRaw - numDk) > 0) {
    var iDate;
    var lastRow = getLastDataRow(earSheet, columnToLetter(earSheet.getRange("EAR_DATES_RNG").getColumn()));
    var distName = impSheet.getRange("A1").getValue().toString();
    var defaultDept = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("All Lists").getRange("A2").getValue().toString();

    impData.forEach(function (entry) {
      iDate = new Date(entry[0]);
      var newEar = earSheet.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":G" + lastRow).getValues(); // init copy

      if (currData.get(iDate.getTime()) == null) {
        newEar[0][0] = entry[0];
        newEar[0][1] = distName;
        newEar[0][6] = entry[1];

        newEar[0][3] = "Royalties";
        newEar[0][4] = defaultDept;
        newEar[0][5] = "NOT SPECIFIED";


        earSheet.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":G" + lastRow).setValues(newEar);

        Logger.log("ADDED: " + entry[1] + " to row: " + lastRow);
        addedNewData++;
        lastRow++;
      }
      else {
        Logger.log("EXISTING DATA FOUND: " + currData.get(iDate.getTime()));
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: you should never find yourself using .getRange() or .getValues() or .setValues() in any kind of "looping" function.
you "read "in the values once.  then you "manipulate" them. then you "set" them back to the sheet.

Comment: @MattKing Hi Matt, thanks for your feedback. Is it safe to assume that between grabbing the values and setting them back to the sheet that the sheet won't change significantly to the point where it might mess something up?

Comment: push each newEar into array and use setValues at the end

Comment: @Cooper just posted an answer, let me know if it is in line with what you had in mind

Comment: I don't know because your code is incomplete.  That's why I did not provide a complete answer when I first commented

Comment: I would guess that if you provide us with a complete example the code that we provide will run faster and be much smaller.

Comment: @Cooper unfortunately the full code is 300 lines plus, but it does appear that the solution is working and much faster; i placed get and set calls outside the loop as suggested

Answer (score 1):

Using Matt and Cooper's suggestions, I came up with this revised code which is significantly faster:

````
  if ((numRaw - numDk) > 0) {
    var iDate;
    var prevLastRow = getLastDataRow(earSheet, columnToLetter(earSheet.getRange("EAR_DATES_RNG").getColumn()));
    var currLastRow = getLastDataRow(earSheet, columnToLetter(earSheet.getRange("EAR_DATES_RNG").getColumn()));
    var rangeSize = numRaw;
    var distName = impSheet.getRange("A1").getValue().toString();
    var defaultDept = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("All Lists").getRange("A2").getValue().toString();

    var newEar = earSheet.getRange("A" + prevLastRow + ":G" + (prevLastRow + rangeSize - 1)).getValues(); // init copy

    impData.forEach(function (entry) {
      iDate = new Date(entry[0]);
      
      if (currData.get(iDate.getTime()) == null) {
        newEar[currLastRow-2][0] = entry[0];
        newEar[currLastRow-2][1] = distName;
        newEar[currLastRow-2][6] = entry[1];

        newEar[currLastRow-2][3] = "Royalties";
        newEar[currLastRow-2][4] = defaultDept;
        newEar[currLastRow-2][5] = "NOT SPECIFIED";

        Logger.log("ADDED: " + entry[1] + " to row: " + currLastRow);
        addedNewData++;
        currLastRow++;
      }
      else {
        Logger.log("EXISTING DATA FOUND: " + currData.get(iDate.getTime()));
      }
    });

    earSheet.getRange("A" + prevLastRow + ":G" + (prevLastRow + rangeSize - 1)).setValues(newEar);
  }```
````